# Почему не работает локальный сервер(lamp) без интернета?

Tags: linux, сервер, lamp

не работает локальный сервер(lamp) без подключения к интернету.
В чем может быть проблема?
Ставил все из коробки. 
Linux.

**UPD:**
Установлен. Все прекрасно работает с интернетом, т.е. загружается мой созданный домен `test.dev` , загружается `phpmyadmin`, `localhost`. Когда отключаешься интернет, заходишь на свой домен - пишет *There is no Internet connection*, на `localhost` заходит исправно и все грузится.
Не пишет никаких ошибок.

Comment: Уже установленный или вы пытаетесь установить?

Comment: Больше подробностей, пожалуйста. Не работает - это как: не загружается ОС (что пишет?), какой-то процесс (какой?) падает с ошибкой (с какой?), пятисотит, что-то ещё?

Comment: Установлен. Все прекрасно работает с интернетом, т.е. загружается мой созданный домен `test.dev` , загружается `phpmyadmin`, `localhost`. Когда отключаешься интернет, заходишь на свой домен - пишет _There is no Internet connection_, на `localhost` заходит исправно и все грузится.
Не пишет никаких ошибок.

Comment: @E.Gableev, ну так без доступа к инернету ваш локальный компьютер не может преобразовать доменное имя в ip-адрес. это нормально и никакого отношения ни к одной из перечисленных в вопросе программ не имеет.

Comment: @E.Gableev, как подсказывает гадалка, Вам необходимо либо на вашей машине заполнить файл /etc/hosts, либо установить DNS сервер, прописать в нём вашу зону и настроить его на вашей машине как основной.

Comment: Во всех (каких, кстати?) браузерах? wget/curl работают?